# Содержимое txt файла передать переменной (например test) в js

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Есть файл на серве http://...../test.txt

Файл содержит только одну строку

Как содержимое этого файла передать переменной (например test) в js?

Answer (score 5):

Через JS содержимое не вытащить. Нужно использовать AJAX
Примерный код JS (с использованием jQuery):

```
var test;
$.ajax({
        url: "test.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        async: true,
        success: function(msg){
            test = msg;
            alert('Содержимое файла: '+test);
        }
    });
```

Comment: То есть по вашему асинхронный запрос к публичному файл не пройдет?

Comment: Да, спасибо, точно

Answer (score 5):

Понадобится промежуточный элемент, куда будем загружать данные из файла.
Пусть у него будет определенный id. Например, "temp".
Пусть файл, откуда загружаем данные, называется "test.txt" и содержит одну строчку: "123456"

Пример загрузки данных на jQuery:

```
var myVar = 0;
// Создали промежуточный блок div#temp
var tempDiv = $('body').append($('<div/>').attr('id', 'temp')).find('#temp');
// Загрузили данные в этот блок
tempDiv.load("/test.txt");
// Записали ответ в переменную
myVar = tempDiv.text();
// Удалили промежуточный блок
tempDiv.remove();

console.log(myVar); // Выведет 123456 (string)
```

Comment: Мне кажется этот метод странным. И напоминает буферезацию вывода PHP и её использование в неуместных местах. Я думаю, что данный метод сделали для подгрузки каких-то отдельных блоков сайта. Но чисто моё мнение, может метод и хорош, т.к. не требует серверного языка, просто мне нравится когда в программировании всё используется по назначению.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться Fetch API, учтите что это асинхронная функция, выполнение которой нужно дождаться:

```
const responce = await fetch('https://example.com/test.txt')
```

далее нужно обработать ответ, это тоже асинхронная функция:

```
const text = await response.text() // const json = response.json() если это объект json.
```

Это пример получения, по хорошему нужно обернуть всё в асинхронную функцию и написать обработчик ошибок, так как await останавливает выполнение кода в текущем контексте.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  async: false
 }).responseText;
```

[Некоторые примеры](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81 - много примеров - не реклама - факт

Comment: Пожалуйста, в следующий раз добавляйте ссылку с примерами прямо в ответ, а не отдельно комментариями.