# Вывод текста из .txt на страницу при помощи JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Я довольно кривой новичок, слабо смыслю в написании кода, иногда способен адаптировать чужой код под свои задачи, но не более. Пару дней бьюсь безрезультатно в поисках решения для небольшой задачки.

Суть задачки в том, чтобы выполнить код на стороне клиента и выводить из периодически перезаписывающегося .txt файла, содержащего одну строчку, на HTML страницу и отображением этого текста на странице в реальном времени. Необходимы такие извращения из-за того, что та визуальная среда, которая используется, имеет мало функционала, а адекватное внедрение кастомных решений без костылей только на основе HTML страниц. (OBS Studio)

Перепробовал множество вариантов кода путём копипасты, однако, у меня же ничего не получается с банальным выводом текста на страницу. JavaScript не строгое обязательное требование, но по тому описанию, что я смог найти, PHP не подходит из-за клиент-сайда. Если я ошибаюсь, то, пожалуйста, поправьте.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Testing</title>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="msg"></div>
    <div id="test"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

И script.js

```
    var test;
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        async: true,
        success: function(msg){
            test = msg;
            alert('Содержимое файла: '+test);
        }
    });
```

Данный код был взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320008). Как я понял, данный код вызывал алерт из кода Script.js с текстом из файлика в ту программу, в которой используется, поэтому его вставил как пример.

Answer (score 0):

js не позволяет читать локальные файлы, кроме как для отправки, поскольку это является серьезной угрозой безопасности. Существуют костыли, позволяющие настроить браузер чтобы подобное разрешить, но в общем и целом это не решение. все же вам придется использовать полноценную связку фронт/бэк

Answer (score 0):

Лучше на сервере сделать php-скрипт

```
<?php 
$filename = 'myfile.txt';
$out = file_get_contents($filename,true);
?>

<p><?php echo $out ?></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

На сервере php скрипт, который при обращении выводит содержимое txt файла, как посоветовал [Denis i](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1097092/239042).
На клиенте js, который с определённым интервалом дёргает данные с сервера и выводит на экран.